# php - not sure how to describe

Tags: php

I got images in a php includes file.

```
<img class="imgmove" src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("images/form/firstname.png")); ?>'>
```

code works flawless. I was testing the design and I dragged an image in to an input bar and it spit back the following:

data:image/png;base64,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

What is all of that code? can someone tell me? Thanks -- and should I be securing my php file so that it doesn't show this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the base64 data uri for the image you dragged in . There is not an issue with you php file from what I understand.

Comment: Ok thanks -  I was just wondering if it contained any sensitive data that needed to be secured.

Comment: yeah nothing to worry about. It's just the base64 -- basically a level up from binary -- data of your image

Answer (score 1):

You ran base64_encode on the image. That is what base64_encode does, it encodes the image data as base64. What you pasted is what base64 looks like.